# Is it possible to show the Notification Badge in Android from application code?

Tags: android, badge, android-launcher

I understand the Notification Badge on the launcher icon in Android (8.0+) is automatically shown when a notification is received.  Unfortunately, once they open or dismiss the notification the badge will be removed.  What I'm wondering is, can the app itself directly tell the system to show the badge?  I would like to show it when they have unread messages within the app.

I understand that some third party launchers and manufacturer variants of Android do offer additional badge functionality, however, I am referring to vanilla Android and the stock launcher.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#set_custom_notification_count

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes I did see that, however I am talking about showing the dot/badge itself on the launcher icon, not setting the count that you see in the long press menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand the Notification Badge on the launcher icon in Android (8.0+) is automatically shown when a notification is received

Only if the launcher supports it. There are hundreds of launchers.

> can the app itself directly tell the system to show the badge?

In terms of the standard Android SDK system, the badge will only appear if you raise a notification. Some launchers may offer an additional (documented or undocumented) API for apps to display badges on icons.

Comment: I should have clarified that I was referring to vanilla Android and the stock launcher.  I will update my question.  Your answer confirmed my suspicion though.

Comment: @asymptoticFault: "I was referring to vanilla Android" -- I do not know what you consider "vanilla Android" to be. "and the stock launcher" -- there are dozens of launchers that ship pre-installed on Android devices.

Comment: I'm referring to the Pixel devices primarily.

Comment: @asymptoticFault: Early Pixel models were indeed fairly vanilla, though they have been trending away from that more recently. They should all ship with the Pixel Launcher, which AFAIK has no APIs to let you manipulate the badge except via the `Notification` system.

Comment: Right, and it's that baseline that I believe the developer documentation is based on.  Thanks for the info.